# How to display subtotal based on sumproduct of input quantity and price?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to display the subtotal of my appetizers section of the menu. Each appetizers item is $3 per guest but then i have to multiply that number by 1.25.

For my JavaScript I tried this

```
var guestsQTY = document.getElementById('guests').value;
var percentage = 1.25;

function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("app");
  var appItemTotal = 0;
  var appSubTotal = (appItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage);
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      appItemTotal += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  appSubTotal += (appItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage);
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + appSubTotal.toFixed(2);
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <h1>Appetizers Selection - $3 per person </h1>
    <p style="font-size:15px;"> *each selection of an appetizer is $3 per estimate number of guests</p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()" /> Meat Pie - Flaky pastry filled with minced beef, onions and green peppers</label>
    <br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()" /> Chin Chin - Fried pastry chips</label>
    <br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()" /> Spring Rolls - Fried flour wrappings with tender-crisp vegetables filling</label>
    <br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()" /> Deviled Eggs - Stuffed eggs with yolk paste & mayo topped with paprika</label>
    <br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()" /> Kelewele - Fried plantains seasoned with spices</label>
    <br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()" /> Kebab - Spicy meat skewers; choose your meat! (one meat per skewer)</label>
    <br><br>
    <label>
        Total Appetizers Costs:
        <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total" />
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

So the expected output that I am trying to get would be something like 
 (appitem1 * guestsQTY * 1.25) + (appitem2 * guestsQTY * 1.25)

Comment: Right, and what's the problem? What's happening currently?

Comment: @Utkanos  The expected output would be the something like (appitem1 * guestsQTY * 1.25) + (appitem2 * guestsQTY * 1.25)

Comment: the guest part is missing.

Comment: @NinaScholz where exactly?

Comment: i miss the gest input somewhere (i added it at in the answer on top). do you have a percent value or just a factor?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an input for the guests and calculate the value.

```js
function totalIt() {
  var guestsQTY = +document.getElementById('guests').value || 0, // default
      input = document.getElementsByName("app"),
      appItemTotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].checked) appItemTotal += +input[i].value;
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + (appItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage).toFixed(2);
}

var percentage = 1.25;
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <h1>Appetizers Selection - $3 per person </h1>
  <p style="font-size:15px;"> *each selection of an appetizer is $3 per estimate number of guests</p>
  Guests: <input type="text" value="" id="guests"><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()"/> Meat Pie - Flaky pastry filled with minced beef, onions and green peppers</label>
  <br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()"/> Chin Chin - Fried pastry chips</label>
  <br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()"/> Spring Rolls -  Fried flour wrappings with tender-crisp vegetables filling</label>
  <br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()"/> Deviled Eggs - Stuffed eggs with yolk paste & mayo topped with paprika</label>
  <br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()"/> Kelewele -  Fried plantains seasoned with spices</label>
  <br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="app" value="3" onclick="totalIt()"/> Kebab - Spicy meat skewers; choose your meat! (one meat per skewer)</label>
  <br><br>
  <label>
      Total Appetizers Costs:
      <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total"/>
    </label>
</fieldset>
```